# Adding glyphicon images in AngularJS ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid, glyphicons

I want to  have a glyphicon icon and be able to add a record in AngularJS ui-grid on left hand side of the panel.

1. want to add glyphicon image and add an event when user clicks it that will add an empty editable row.
2. I  want to get the angularjs ui-grid data as json and call micro services rest api how to do that ?

Comment: need more information to answer this - it is not clear

Comment: I am developing  a CRUD application using  angularjs UI-grid, ui bootstrap.

Comment: I  want to add glyphicon images on the left side of  the ui-grid panel UI look similar as below  http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

Comment: glyphicon images  
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp  This is to be added at the left side of panel and when the user click + symbol   It should add a blank row and allow them to enter data. After that they should send  all entered data thru  rest api calls.   How to call restful ap also ?

Comment: is there a way i can attach screen shots , which i am developing ?

Comment: this is very urgent and I am held up because of this. Also no proper documentation available for Angular UI grid , ui bootstrap etc.

Comment: you are actually asking 2 different questions in one post, you should ask only one coherent question and provide ask much as useful information so people could better help you (code snippets, screen shots etc..)

Comment: can you at least answer to 1 question.